# Find the maximum value of expression

Tags: derivatives, optimization

Find the maximum value of expression $x^3y-3y^2x^2$, if $0\le x\le 3$ and $0\le y\le 3$.

I found the value $10.125$ by just applying the values from given range. Would be better to know proper mathematical way of solving

Answer (score 2):

The maximum (and minimum) of a differentiable function, on a closed and bounded region, must be on the boundary or a point in the interior where the derivative is 0.  Since this is a function of the two variables, x and y, the derivative is 0 if and only if the two partial derivatives are 0.  What are the partial derivatives of $f(x, y)= x^3y- 3x^2y^2$?  Where are they both equal to 0?  Are those points in this region?  On the boundary, x= 0, the function is $f(0, y)= 0$, a constant function.  Similarly, on the boundary, y= 0, the function is $f(x, 0)= 0$.  On the boundary, x= 3, the function is $f(3, y)= 27y- 2y^2$.  On the boundary, y= 3, the function is $f(x, 3)= 3x^3- 27x$.  Find the maximum value of that on the given interval.  You might also need to check the value of f at the vertices, (0, 0), (3, 0), (0, 3), and (3, 3).